# Processing 3.5.3 Rotating points around center point Image shrinking in size and dissapears

Tags: rotation, processing

My problem is as in the title. I am trying to write a simple game in processing with a car that you can drive on a 2D plane. I wanted to create a rotation of the car since it seems crucial so I did it as described here:[Rotating points in 2D](https://matthew-brett.github.io/teaching/rotation_2d.html)

But my implementation seems to fail a bit. You see, when I hit left of right arrow the car actually rotates but shrinks in size as it is rotating and after few turns it completely dissapears. Can you show me what am I missing here? Thanks in advance! Code of my functions:

```
 class Point
{
   float x, y;
   Point(float xx, float yy)
   {
     x = xx;
     y = yy;
   }
   Point()
   {
      x = y = 0.0; 
   }
   void Rotate(Point center, float angle)
   {
     float s = sin(angle);
     float c = cos(angle);
      y = center.y + ((y-center.y) * c + (x-center.x) * s);
      x = center.x + ((x-center.x) * c - (y-center.y) * s);
   }
}
class Car
{
    Point LT;
    Point RT;
    Point LB;
    Point RB;
    Point center;
    float r;
    float acceleration;
    Car()
    {
       LT = new Point(10, 10);
       RT = new Point (30, 10);
       LB = new Point(10, 50);
       RB = new Point(30, 50);
       r = sqrt(pow(15-30, 2) + pow(25-10, 2));
    }
    Car(Point lt, Point rt, Point lb, Point rb)
    {
       LT = lt;
       RT = rt;
       LB = lb;
       RB = rb;
       center = new Point(abs((LT.x - RT.x)/2), abs((LT.y - LB.y)/2));
       r = sqrt(pow(center.x -LT.x, 2) + pow(center.y - LT.y, 2));
    }
    Car(Point Center, float w, float h)
    {
       center = Center;
       LT = new Point(center.x - w/2, center.y - h/2);
       RT = new Point (center.x + w/2, center.y - h/2);
       LB = new Point(center.x - w/2, center.y + h/2);
       RB = new Point(center.x + w/2, center.y + h/2);
       r = sqrt(pow(center.x -LT.x, 2) + pow(center.y - LT.y, 2));
    }
    void Show()
    {
       fill(45, 128, 156);
       beginShape(); 
       vertex(LT.x, LT.y);
       vertex(RT.x, RT.y);
       vertex(RB.x, RB.y);
       vertex(LB.x, LB.y);          
       endShape();
    }
    void Update()
    {

    }
    void Turn(float angle)
    {
      LT.Rotate(center, angle);
      RT.Rotate(center, angle);
      RB.Rotate(center, angle);
      LB.Rotate(center, angle);
    }
    void Accelerate(float accel)
    {

    }
}
```

In main I only use car.Show() and I turn by -0.1 per left cliock and 0.1 per right click

**EDIT**
If you want to see whole code visit my [github repo](https://github.com/TheFunnySunny/Processing-3-car-game)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I can't explain more at the moment, but here's a simpler option using one of the formulas you've pointed to:

```
Car car = new Car();

void setup(){
  size(300,300);
  // this helps draw rectangles from centre (as opposed to corner (default))
  rectMode(CENTER);

  car.position.set(150,150);
}

void draw(){
  background(255);
  if(keyPressed){
    if(keyCode == UP){
      car.speed = 1;
    }
  }
  car.draw();
}

void keyPressed(){
  if(keyCode == LEFT){
    car.steer -= radians(10);
  }
  if(keyCode == RIGHT){
    car.steer += radians(10);
  }
}
void keyReleased(){
  if(keyCode == UP){
    car.speed = 0;
  }
}

class Car{

  PVector position = new PVector();
  PVector velocity = new PVector();

  float speed;
  float steer;

  void update(){
    // use the same polar to cartesian coordinates formulate for quick'n'dirty steering
    velocity.set(cos(steer) * speed,sin(steer) * speed);
    // update position based on velocity
    position.add(velocity);
  }

  void draw(){
    update();
    // use a nested coordinate system to handle translation and rotation for us
    // order of operations is important
    pushMatrix();
      translate(position.x,position.y);
      rotate(steer);
      rect(0,0,30,15);
    popMatrix();
  }
}
```

**Update**

The main issue with points shrinking is you're cumulatively transforming the points when you rotate them. After each transformation there is no history of what the x,y were. Instead you should return a new point that is transformed, thus "remembering" the old x,y position.

Bellow is a tweaked version of your code, minus the two constructor variants.
Hopefully the comments will help:

```
Car car = new Car();

void setup(){
  size(300,300);
}

void draw(){

  if(keyCode == UP){
    if(keyPressed){
      car.Accelerate(1);
    }else{
      car.Accelerate(0);
    }
  }

  car.Update();

  background(255);
  car.Show();

}


void keyPressed(){
  if(keyCode == LEFT){
    car.Turn(radians(-3));
  }
  if(keyCode == RIGHT){
    car.Turn(radians(+3));
  }
}

class Point
{
   float x, y;
   Point(float xx, float yy)
   {
     x = xx;
     y = yy;
   }
   Point()
   {
      x = y = 0.0; 
   }

   Point Rotate(Point center, float angle)
   {
     float s = sin(angle);
     float c = cos(angle);
     // return a new point (a rotated copy), rather than overwriting this one
     return new Point(center.x + ((x-center.x) * c - (y-center.y) * s),
                      center.y + ((y-center.y) * c + (x-center.x) * s));
   }
   // translate by another point
   void AddToSelf(Point point){
     this.x += point.x;
     this.y += point.y;
   }
   // pretty print info when using println()
   String toString(){
     return "[Point x=" + x + " y="+ y +"]";
   }

}
class Car
{
    Point LT;
    Point RT;
    Point LB;
    Point RB;

    Point center;

    float r;
    float acceleration;

    // car angle: used to compute velocity and update vertices
    float angle;
    // car position: used to offset rendering position of the corners
    Point position;
    // car velocity: amount by which position translates
    Point velocity = new Point();

    Car()
    {
       float x = 10;
       float y = 10;
       float w = 40;
       float h = 20;
       // setup corners with no translation
       LT = new Point(0    , 0    );
       RT = new Point(0 + w, 0    );
       LB = new Point(0    , 0 + h);
       RB = new Point(0 + w, 0 + h);
       // setup initial position
       position = new Point(x,y);

       center = new Point(w / 2, h / 2);

       r = sqrt(pow(15-30, 2) + pow(25-10, 2));
    }
    //Car(Point lt, Point rt, Point lb, Point rb)
    //{
    //   LT = lt;
    //   RT = rt;
    //   LB = lb;
    //   RB = rb;
    //   center = new Point(abs((LT.x - RT.x)/2), abs((LT.y - LB.y)/2));
    //   r = sqrt(pow(center.x -LT.x, 2) + pow(center.y - LT.y, 2));
    //}
    //Car(Point Center, float w, float h)
    //{
    //   center = Center;
    //   LT = new Point(center.x - w/2, center.y - h/2);
    //   RT = new Point (center.x + w/2, center.y - h/2);
    //   LB = new Point(center.x - w/2, center.y + h/2);
    //   RB = new Point(center.x + w/2, center.y + h/2);
    //   r = sqrt(pow(center.x -LT.x, 2) + pow(center.y - LT.y, 2));
    //}
    void Show()
    {
       fill(45, 128, 156);
       beginShape(); 
       // render corners offset by the car position
       vertex(position.x + LT.x, position.y + LT.y);
       vertex(position.x + RT.x, position.y + RT.y);
       vertex(position.x + RB.x, position.y + RB.y);
       vertex(position.x + LB.x, position.y + LB.y);          
       endShape(CLOSE);
    }
    void Update()
    {
      // update velocity based on car angle and acceleration
      velocity.x = cos(angle) * acceleration;
      velocity.y = sin(angle) * acceleration;
      // update position based on velocity
      position.AddToSelf(velocity);

    }
    void Turn(float angle)
    {
      this.angle += angle;
      // replace the old point with the transformed points 
      // (rather than continuosly transforming the same point)
      LT = LT.Rotate(center, angle);
      RT = RT.Rotate(center, angle);
      RB = RB.Rotate(center, angle);
      LB = LB.Rotate(center, angle);
    }

    void Accelerate(float accel)
    {
      acceleration = accel;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You very much for Your solution, I will check it out tomorrow morning but I am really curious why is it shrinking when I am doing it my way, still can not find any reasonable explanation

Comment: @TheFunnySunny See my updated notes above. I know it's not an exhaustive answer but hopefully this answers your question (if so, feel free to vote and/or mark the answer ;) )

Comment: Oh my You are right! Okay, that helped a lot, I understand why it happend, thnk You for Your time!!